# Can you make 2 cell 1 on the other within one tr tag?

Tags: html, html-table

What I want is something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which creates a table like this: [image: the table i get]

but what I want is something like this: [image: the table I want]

I know I can easily make it with adding a new row and using `rowspan` to fix it, but if there is another way to do it without adding another row, it will be so great

Comment: Why do you not want to add another row?

Comment: May be consider a2 & a3 as two elements in a single cell

Comment: @LionelRowe because i use it with DataTables and it thinks it is a new row when i download it as Excel

Comment: @SeeoX i tried it and i think it is my only way to do it

Comment: In Excel, this would also need to be implemented as two rows, with a1 and a4 merged into the cells below. Sounds like you just need to find a way to customize the styling of the exported Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that using `rowspan`.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i know how to do it without adding another row, but is there any athor way without adding it?

Comment: There is no way. If you really want to do, you can update the style of default `tr` and `td` to use `grid` layout. Current `tr`, `td` uses `table` layout for display and you should change that to use `grid` layout display. But it's not good to change the default `tr`, `td` styles.

Answer (score -1):

the answer I got after so many searches was this 2 without adding another Row:

1. adding both a2 a3 to another cell.
2. using grid system instead of table.

and there are other ways and the easiest ways is by adding another row, the code looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">a4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```